# Stop users from entering text into an textarea field after a certain amount of characters have been entered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop users from entering data into a textarea after the character count has reached its limit. And is it possible for the character count to keep track of how many characters have been entered even after the page has been refreshed?

Jquery

```
    $('.character-count').text('4000 characters left');
    $('#description').keyup(function(){
        var max = 4000;
        var len = $(this).val().length;
        var ch = max - len;
        $('.character-count').text(ch + ' characters left');
    });
```

Comment: set the count value in a `cookie`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var max = 10;

$('#description')
.keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46 && $(this).val().length >= max) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
.keyup(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val().slice(0, max),
        val_length = val.length,
        left = max - val_length;

    $('.character-count').text(left + ' characters left');

    $this.val(val);
});
```

After each keyup textarea value is cut off after `max` symbols.

Keydown event is blocking after value length reached `max`,
but you can still press backspace (`8`) or delete (`46)` keys.

Comment: Oh, you want to remember all previous input, hmm

Comment: I want it to stop the user from entering as soon the limit is reached this still lets the user enter but it jumps back when the amount has been entered.

Comment: But now the number of characters is not displayed at first other wise its good.

Comment: I figured it but is there a way I can add multiple character counts for multiple fields on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

use local storage in order to deal with later use

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="userText" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div class="character-count"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(function(){
    var comment = $('#description');
    var val = localStorage.getItem( comment.attr('id') ),
        max = 4000,
        len = val.length,
        left = ( max - len ) ;
    // if the value exists, set it
    if (val) {
        comment.val(val);
        $('.character-count').text( left + ' Character(s) left');
    }
});

$('#description').on('keyup', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        max = 4000,
        val = $this.val(),
        val_length = val.length,
        remain = ((max - val_length)>=0)?(max - val_length):0;

    $('.character-count').text(remain + ' Character(s) left');
    if( val_length > max ){
        $this.val(val.slice(0,max));
    }
    // let's check if localStorage is supported
    if (window.localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    }


});
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/krzyLk43/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in HTML5 attribute `maxlength`, which will restrict the count of entered symbols. There is no need to reinvent it yourself:

```js
$("input").on('input', function() {
  var left = this.maxLength - this.value.length;
  $("span").text(left + " characters left");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" maxlength="5"/>
<span>5 characters left</span>
```

Also, if you use `keyup` handler, then the user can easily type your text somewhere else and paste as many characters as he wants. Use `input`.

Talking about "to keep track of how many characters have been entered even after the page has been refreshed", you may use cookies, but it is a doubtful feature. Any user can easily replace or empty any cookies or other local storage. If this limitation is really important, implement it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the entire text entered by the user in the cookie as suggested by coolguy and on refresh you can just retrieve the cookie data and display in the text area as well as the character count tracker.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            var descText = $.cookie('description');
            var descTextArea = $('#description');
            var maxLength = descTextArea.data('maxLength');
            if (descText) {
                descTextArea.text(descText);
                $('.character-count').text((maxLength - descText.length) + ' characters left');
            }
            else {
                $('.character-count').text(maxLength + ' characters left');

            }
            descTextArea.keydown(function (event) {
               var max = maxLength;
               var len = $(this).val().length;
               var ch = max - len;
               if (ch < 0 ) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  return false;
               }
               $('.character-count').text(ch + ' characters left');
               $.cookie('description', $(this).val(), {path: '/'});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Using keydown after referring answer by legotin.
HTML file is:

```
<textarea id="description" data-max-length="4000"></textarea>
<span class="character-count"></span>
```

I am using [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() to stop handling.

```
e.preventDefault();


$('.character-count').html('20 characters left');
var len = 0;
var max = 20;
$('#description').keydown(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if(len == max && code != 8)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    len = $(this).val().length;
    var ch = max - len;
    $('.character-count').text(ch + ' characters left');
});
```

try this
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paceer26/1/)